# What is the format of shell history files

Tags: bash, shell, unix, zsh, history

My `~/.zsh_history` shows:

```
: 1449561637:0;echo "foobar"
```

I'm guessing it goes `unix timestamp` `:` `exit code` `;` `command` but what about the space before the timestamp and first colon?

Is there an official spec?

Comment: Please note that bash has different format. It has only the commands you run.

Comment: I believe there's no official spec. It's undocumented, but it's pretty easy to understand.

Comment: @alnet You can set `HISTTIMEFORMAT` in `bash` to tag each entry with a timestamp as well.

Comment: There's nothing official, because each shell will implement its own history file format.

Answer (score 7):

As already noted in the comments, the format of the history file depends on the shell and sometimes even on specific settings of the shell.

In your case you are using `zsh` with the `EXTENDED_HISTORY` option enabled (either by explicitly setting it or by using `csh`-emulation). According to the [ZSH manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#History) the format of history entries with `EXTENDED_HISTORY` is as follows:

```
: <beginning time>:<elapsed seconds>;<command>
```

So the space before the timestamp is just part of the format and the number between the second colon an the semicolon is actually the time taken by the command and not the exit code.

**Note**: `<elapsed seconds>` will always be `0`, if the `INC_APPEND_HISTORY` option is set, because then the history entry is written to the file immediately after entering the command. If you want to log the duration and keep sharing the history between shell sessions, you may want to use `INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME` instead. This writes to the history file only after the command completed.

Comment: If `INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME` is set, does that mean that commands that don't exit (or crash) will not get written to the history file?

I wish there were a way to have the best of both worlds.  Be able to show how long each command takes while also guaranteeing all commands are there

Comment: @MaxCoplan As long as the command exits in any way that returns you to the shell prompt (normal exit, error codes, segmentation fault, etc. ) `zsh` will append the command to the history file. Only if the shell itself also exits (closing the terminal window, shutting down, etc.) while or immediately after, then `zsh` might not be able to write the entry. It might be possible to work around this limitation by writing/editing the history file via `preexec` and/or `precmd` hooks. But this might take some effort, especially if it should work with multiple parallel `zsh` sessions.